# Unable to download file from website

Tags: google-chrome, html

On my personal website I have this simple line of HTML:

```
<a href="file.zip">Click here to download file.zip</a>
```

I tested it on two different computers using chrome and firefox, win7 and win8 and it works no problem. However when a friend tries to click the link he gets this error message:

> No data received
>
> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
>
> Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

He is using win7, chrome.

What could possibly be the reason that he is unable to download the file?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give me the link? So I can test it? I understand it's a personal website, so if not, it's alright, just tell me :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't want to link to the actual site here. I can tell you that it only contains the bare minimum html code to display an empty page with the link, there is nothing else on there.

Comment: OK, it's alright :). Some simple things to try: ***1.*** Change the url to google, ask him again. This will check whether the problem is with the website or his computer. ***2.*** Ask him to try another computer/browser. This will check, again, whether the problem is with the computer/browser, or the website. ***3.*** Make sure you've actually uploaded the HTML page, not just using the local, cached version. You might have forgotten to do so!

Comment: It could be that you need to add a directory path within the web-site, eg ... href="/path/to/file/file.zip" ...

Comment: Thanks I will try the thing with google. I will also get him to try a different browser asap, however when I tested it in chrome it worked for me, so I don't understand what the difference would be.

Comment: @ṧнʊß As for 3. I was able to download the file on another computer that could not possibly have had a cached version, so I don't think that's the cause. I will tell my friend to reset his cache just in.. case.

Comment: @ṧнʊß - The file could be in his current directory when he is doing his local test. If the friend hovers over the link and writes down the link which should show in the browser, or right-clicks and copies the link target location, then this will give a clue as to the location of the file. Or it could be access permissions on the file.

Comment: @AFH OK, but when he's uploaded it, he already knows the location of the file. Why does the friend need to find it out? It has to be in the same directory as the HTML page because it's relative?